# Why does the King James Bible have the words "of God" in 1 John 3:16 whereas most translations do not have the words "of God" included?

Tags: translation-philosophy, 1-john

[1 John 3:16 KJB](https://www.stepbible.org/?q=version=ESV%7Cversion=NETfull%7Cversion=NIV%7Cversion=THGNT%7Cversion=VulgCC%7Cversion=DRC%7Cversion=VulgJ%7Cversion=KJVA%7Cversion=CPDV%7Creference=1John.3.16&options=GVNUVH&display=INTERLEAVED)

Hereby perceive we the love of God, because he laid down his life for us: and we ought to lay down our lives for the brethren.

Comment: related https://bible.org/article/textual-problem-1-john-57-8

Comment: see http://textus-receptus.com/wiki/1_John_3:16

Comment: The reason why becomes clear when reading a few verses further on: "In this was manifested the love of God toward us, because that God sent his only begotten Son into the world, that we might live through him. Herein is love, not that we loved God, but that he loved us, and sent his Son..." (4:9-10). Also, Jesus said "Greater love hath no man than this, that a man lay down his life for his friends (John 15:13). Knowing this excludes any false idea that God laid down his life. It was the Son who laid down his life, the Father having sent him, in love. The Father did not die. The Son died.

Answer (score 4):

The addition "of God" in the text of the KJV is highlighted as an added text because it italicized.  It is absent in the Greek and thus should not be there.  Here is the literal translation from BLB of V16 & 17

> By this we have known love, because **He** laid down His life for us;
> and we ought to lay down our lives for our brothers. Now whoever might
> have the world's goods, and might see his brother having need, and
> might close up his heart from him, how does the **love of God** abide
> in him?

One assumes that in V16, "in God" was justified because of the phrase "love of God" in V17, highlighted above.

The real question is, who is the antecedent for the demonstrative pronoun, ἐκεῖνος = "he", or "that man" also highlighted above.  We have the following grammatical precedents, in order of ascending distance:

- Cain (V12) - this cannot be the case
- the evil one (V12) - this cannot be the case
- God (10)
- the Devil (V10) - this cannot be the case
- God (V9)
- the Devil (V8) - this cannot be the case
- the Son of God (V8)
- the Devil (V8) - this cannot be the case
- Christ (V5)

On grammatical grounds alone, one cannot argue for "the Devil" because it is too far away, thus, the closest and most grammatical antecedent for "he" in V16, is "God" in V10.

Thus, on two bases, "love of God" in V17 and the only grammatically possible antecedent for "he" is God.  However, this still does not justify the unwarranted insertion of the text by the KJV, which has now been corrected by the NKJV.

However, the most probable reason for the inclusion of "of God" in V16 is its existence in the Clementine text of the Latin Vulgate which reads:

> In hoc cognovimus caritatem **Dei**, quoniam ille animam suam pro
> nobis posuit : et nos debemus pro fratribus animas ponere. = In this
> we have known the charity **of God**, because he hath laid down his
> life for us: and we ought to lay down our lives for the brethren.

This is yet another instance where the KJV translators chose the Latin text over the Greek text.

Comment: The controversial Latin readings were forced in the Textus Receptus versions. Erasmus had to add the trinitarian formula by public demand as they created a greek copy just for that. So, this verse was similarly made into Greek in the Scrivener's TR version. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King_James_Version#New_Testament and https://textusreceptusbibles.com/Interlinear/62003016

Comment: @Michael16 - unfortunately, there are dozens more!

Answer (score 0):

> ἐν τούτῳ ἐγνώκαμεν τὴν ἀγάπην, ὅτι ἐκεῖνος ὑπὲρ ἡμῶν τὴν ψυχὴν αὑτοῦ
> ἔθηκεν καὶ ἡμεῖς ὀφείλομεν ὑπὲρ τῶν ἀδελφῶν τὰς ψυχὰς τιθέναι (1 John
> 3:16, TR)

While there are some slight differences in the underlying Greek text between the Majority Text/Textus Receptus (TR) and the so-called Critical Text for this verse (e.g. the very last word being "τιθέναι" versus "θεῖναι"), the words "of God" do not exist in the Greek text.  In the KJV, to show these words were not present in the original, they will usually be italicized.

Understanding why the translators felt the need and/or at liberty to add these words requires understanding Greek grammar at a deeper level.

In Greek, it is common for nouns to be omitted where they have either been mentioned earlier and are still in focus, or where it would be expected that the reader would understand the reference without the noun's repetition.  This differs from English in that an English writer would avoid redundancy by choosing a similar, but different, word: Greek writers avoid redundancy by simply omitting the extra occurrences.

When translating from Greek to English, it is often the case that an omitted noun is required to be reinserted for the English grammar.  Where this is most obviously the case, the publishers may not even choose to italicize the word, as it is both grammatically justified in Greek, and required for English.  However, in cases where the added words are more open to interpretation, or perhaps not absolutely necessary for grammatical sense in English, these words are usually italicized in the KJV to indicate that they have been supplied.

Such is the case here: the KJV translators felt it best to add these words, and indicate this, whereas translators of some of the other versions did not see the necessity of doing so.

For a Trinitarian who believes that Jesus is God, the context of the text would indicate that the addition is consistent with the meaning of the text.

> Hereby perceive we the love of God, **because he laid down his life
> for us:** and we ought to lay down our lives for the brethren. (1 John
> 3:16, KJV)

However, knowing that God is immortal and cannot die (see 1 Timothy 1:17; 1 Timothy 6:16), the addition creates a contradiction in the Bible, essentially saying that *God* had died.

### Conclusion

The additional expression "of God" in the KJV translation of 1 John 3:16 is not justified by the Greek text, and does not belong to the text.  It creates an inconsistency with other scriptures, because it implies that God, who is immortal, had died.

Comment: The stackiverse works in mysterious ways. In Christianity.SE I might argue against this, but here I agree with and up-vote it.